# System using 25% CPU after start up

Tags: windows-7, cpu

After switching on my computer (Win7 ultimate 64) while still doing "nothing" shows me (using Process Explorer), that "System PID4" is actually using 25% of CPU.... 
There are six threads using the CPU, all have the same name: ntoskrnl.exe!ExQueueWorkltem+0x80

How can I find our what causes this and stop this?

(Net Speed Monitor showed no in- or out-going data... I have serached the internet, and tried everything offered)

Thank you

Comment: Have your read this page? "System PID 4" https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/system-in-task-manager-pid-4-takes-too-much-cpu/c80a2a23-1c32-4f4e-8778-16df3b171525 Process Monitor download page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: You should wait 5 min until Windows loads its services and then check the performance.